# where with multiple like not working in codignitor

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to get rows where hospital_id = 802 and multiple or_likes but my query is skipping where hospital_id = 802 but doing filter by or very well something went wrong in query, thanks in advance

**here is my query**

```
SELECT * FROM (`patient`) WHERE `hospital_id` = '802' AND `name` LIKE '%fn%' OR `phone` LIKE '%fn%' OR `nic` LIKE '%fn%' OR `passport` LIKE '%fn%' OR `ticket` LIKE '%fn%' ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

**written in CI**

```
$value = 'fn';
$this->db->or_like('name',$value);
    $this->db->or_like('phone',$value);
    $this->db->or_like('nic',$value);
    $this->db->or_like('passport',$value);
    $this->db->or_like('ticket',$value);
    $rows=$this->db->where('hospital_id',802)->order_by("id", "DESC")->get('patient')->result();
```

can somebody help me in Codeigniter style?

Comment: Try this : SELECT * FROM (`patient`) WHERE ((`hospital_id` = '802') AND (`name` LIKE '%fn%' OR `phone` LIKE '%fn%' OR `nic` LIKE '%fn%' OR `passport` LIKE '%fn%' OR `ticket` LIKE '%fn%')) ORDER BY `id` DESC

Comment: it's working but i don't need raw query i need Active record query for codeigniter $this->db-> ..... style

Answer (score 0):

You have to use group start and group end

```
$this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->or_like('name',$value);
    $this->db->or_like('phone',$value);
    $this->db->or_like('nic',$value);
    $this->db->or_like('passport',$value);
    $this->db->or_like('ticket',$value);
    $this->db->group_end();
    $rows=$this->db->where('hospital_id',802)->order_by("id", "DESC")->get('patient')->result();
```

Comment: it's returning nothing